# Who is Buffy's father?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

> Giles: Buffy, I am your father.
>  Buffy: Nooooooooooooooo!
>  Giles: Search your feelings, you know it to be true.

Ok, so wrong movie.  But in [season 3 episode 18 "Earshot"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0533417/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_pl_syn), Buffy gained the ability to read minds, and found out that:

> Buffy's mom had sex with Giles. Twice.

And it seemed that this event happened a long time ago. Around 16 years ago possibly.  So, does this mean that:

> Giles is Buffy's father?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 17):

The [*Buffy the Vampire Slayer Encyclopedia: The Ultimate Guide to the Buffyverse*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33783445-buffy-the-vampire-slayer-encyclopedia) states that [**Hank Summers**](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Hank_Summers) is her father.

> **SUMMERS, HANK**: ***Father to Buffy** and (later) Dawn;
> ex-husband of Joyce. **Hank was attentive to his daughter when Buffy and
> her mom first moved to Sunnydale**, and he invited Buffy to his home in
> LA for the summer (BtVS “When She Was Bad”). But he eventually dropped
> out of her life altogether by not attending Joyce’s funeral (BtVS “The
> Body”) or helping his children with the bills (BtVS “Flooded”).*

We see him in the Buffy film played by James Canon as well as in the TV series in "[When She Was Bad](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/When_She_Was_Bad)" played by Dean Butler. He also cameos in the episode [Nightmares](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Nightmares) and appears in several of the follow-on comics issues by Mutant Enemy/Dark Horse.

[image]

---

As far as Giles having sex with Buffy's mother, that happened (twice) in the episode "[Band Candy](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Band_Candy)" when both he and her mother reverted mentally to their teen selves.

[image]

Comment: That was way funny.  The two of them acting like teenagers initially, Buffy's discovery of it from her mum and Giles walking into a tree.  LMAO.

Comment: I think we do see Hank Summers, extremely briefly, at the end of *Nightmares*, when he picks Buffy up to spend the weekend with her. He does seem to pretty much disappear from her life after that though; she doesn’t hear back from him even after — HUGE SPOILER ALERT — the death of — SERIOUSLY, HUGE SPOILER ALERT — Joyce.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I've not got time to check whether he was real or just a vision. Feel free to correct my post.

Comment: @Richard: and, really, how could you tell?

Comment: Hank is mentioned several times throughout the series.  Whether he's real or not in "Nightmares", he's in "When She Was Bad".  He is mentioned in *Angel* in the episode "I Will Remember You".  Dawn mentions talking to him in "Bargaining".  And he shows up in "Normal Again".

Comment: @AndrewThompson From what I've heard, Anthony Head wasn't watching where he was going, and *actually* walked into the tree. The timing just happened to be perfect.

Comment: @scott.korin - He was an hallucination in Normal Again but he was definitely real in When She Was Bad which is why I've used that one in the answer.

Comment: Or he was real in *Normal Again* and every other episode was a hallucination.

Comment: @phantom42 - That would certainly explain [this guy](http://images2.fanpop.com/images/quiz/122000/122754_1231819652725_442_442.jpg)

Comment: @Richard I knew who that was going to be before I even clicked. BTW, the direct link doesn't work. I had to spoof the referer.

Comment: Another point against Giles being Buffy's father is that the Summers only move to Sunnydale at the beginning of he series, and there is no indication that Giles and Joyce know each other.